# ReadTheDocs site with 2 long-term version branches

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs

My project has 2 versions that are actively maintained (2.x and 3.x). 3.x is newer but I am still releasing updates to the 2.x documentation.

How can I have 2 branches of my docs on ReadTheDocs? I imagine something like:

```
https://foo.readthedocs.io/en/2.x
https://foo.readthedocs.io/en/3.x
```

Currently, if someone goes to `https://foo.readthedocs.io/en/latest`, they get the 2.x docs, but after 1 year I want to flip that to point to the 3.x docs.

Reading [this](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/rel/versions.html) page, it seems like I want 2 "release branches", but I cannot find more info about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Pyramid's repository](https://github.com/pylons/pyramid) for how we manage branches for publishing our docs on RTD.  We actively maintain three branches, `master`, `1.10-branch`, and `1.9-branch`, where `master` is the development branch and `1.10-branch` is the latest stable released branch.

In RTD under *Admin > Advanced Settings*, we currently configure "latest" as Default version and `1.10-branch` as Default branch.  We also do not delete old branches.  With this configuration, we publish 14 RTD "Versions" of Pyramid, from `1.0-branch` to `2.0-branch`, plus `master` and `latest`.

- https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/master/
- https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/
- https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/2.0-branch/
- https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.10-branch/
- ...and so on.

We also build pull requests as an extra check that docs build successfully because RTD sometimes updates its build environment with a new version of Sphinx.

Comment: What does configuring `1.10-branch` as default branch happens? So if you need 14 RTD versions, will all 14 versions shows in the navigation? Is there a way we can organize this?

Comment: You can have as many branches/versions as you desire. See the links in my answer for the repository for implementation details and how it renders on RTD.

Comment: Like I dont get when the build is happening. I am trying to achieve something like, for `feature_branch2`, changes related to that branch needs to be shown. For `feature_branch3`, changes specific to that needs to be shown. But, in my case, I see that code is mixed. Can you please suggest? I can invite you to my repo?

Comment: A branch is built on RTD when a commit is pushed to the main branch or when you manually tell RTD to build a specific branch. It never builds all branches automatically.